# Excel sumproduct combine multi row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I want to check A1:A10 whether they are repeated themselves in A1:A10.

I know i can use this formula in B1 to B10.

Is it possible to simplify it by one formula?

```
=sumproduct(($a$1:$a$10=A1)*1>1)

=sumproduct(($a$1:$a$10=A1:A10)*1>1) ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10)>1)*(1/COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10)))
```

In this case there are two values that are repeated/have duplicates; `Test3` and `Test4`.

In case your goal was only to count ALL rows that have duplicates (repeated values), you can use `=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10)>1)*1)` which in this case would give you `6`.

**EDIT**

For multiple columns, replace `COUNTIF` with `COUNTIFS` and extend with the columns you want to compare:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(A1:A10,A1:A10,B1:B10,B1:B10)>1)*(1/COUNTIFS(A1:A10,A1:A10,B1:B10,B1:B10)))
```

Comment: Yes, or if the question was just 'Are there any duplicates?' then the second formula.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to expand this formula to check more than one column?  Let say a1:a10 ... e1:e10

Comment: Yes, I'll update the answer @YUI. Kindly accept if this answered your question. I would appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks again.  But it only work when all columns are duplicates.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean? This formula will tell you how often there are values over multiple columns that are exactly the same. A3&B3 are the same as A7&B7. If this is not what you want you can just use the original formula and use `+` to add the same formula but applied to another column.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 with the **new Dynamic Array** functions (currently available in the insider build), you can use the Unique() function and compare a count of the range with a count of the unique values of the range.

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(A1:A10))<>COUNTA(A1:A10)
```

Read more about the new [Dynamic Arrays here.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel-Blog/Preview-of-Dynamic-Arrays-in-Excel/ba-p/252944)

Comment: Thanks.  But i'm using excel 2010.

Comment: I know it is a way to edit the formula.  But i forget.